# Regarding App slicing feature in iOS9

Tags: ios, app-store

One of our old project is now updated to XCode 7 and iOS9 SDK. Some of the images in the project is missing @3x versions and since we have a critical bug we need to submit it soon. We were testing our AdHoc build by 
**"Exporting one app for all compatible devices"** - It is working fine.

What I want to know is, will App Slicing create problem if I dont have @3x images? Is there a way to turn it off?

Meanwhile I am trying hard to get all the 3x images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, This is what happened,

1. I submitted the App without some of the 3x images.
2. App got approved.
3. Released in production, no issues so far related to images.

But one thing I noticed was that the slicing didnt happen. The Universal App size was **65MB** and now also for every device it is showing **65MB** in the AppStore, so i am confused whether the slicing happened or not.